# how to independently transform points without other points moving in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to learn photoshop by myself and while trying to do a project I came across a problem. I have an upside down triangle, so that the tip of the triangle faces down.

now I want to add a sort-of square to the bottom, so that the blue on the box touches the blue on the triangle, green on the box touches the green on the triangle, and the pink bit stays exactly where it is. Is there any way to do this?

------ATTACHMENTS---------

TRIANGLE :: http://s8.postimg.org/hg7bpfpo5/triangle_down.png

DOTS :: http://s15.postimg.org/6wzufwn7f/pro.png

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the `Direct Selection Tool`, it is the one pictured below.
[image: tool]

You can then select the individual `Anchor Point` that you wish to move:
[image: point]

Then move it!
[image: move]